# Gmail app links are not clickable

Tags: gmail, nexus-5, hyperlinks

For some reason any link that comes into my gmail app inside an email is not clickable. Whenever I want to browse to the link I have to drag select the link. I have a default Nexus 5. I have not made any modifications or really changed any settings. Whats the deal???

*** Update ***

This is still a problem (03/15/2016). It makes trying to visit for example forum replies VERY difficult! Does no one else have this problem? Please help!

*** Update ***

Default gmail app - Ver 6.0.115979076

Android - Ver 6.0.1

*** Resolved ***

Turns out this is most likely due to Cisco corporate high security email and phone controls. I cant say for sure, but it makes sense that email links would be one thing they would disable with the security policies. Marking this resolved and awarding points. Thanks

Comment: Why is this question protected when it didn't get any answers?

Comment: I dont know. Would love to find an answer to this question though.

Comment: Adding your Android version and app version to the question might be helpful, as well as an example of a link (to rule out a formatting issue). Do you have any type of anti-virus installed?

Comment: Versions added above

Comment: No anti virus currently

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139697/how-to-get-mail-with-clickable-links

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Because it's had four "I have this problem too" answers by new/unregistered users, which have been deleted.

Comment: @Atomiklan Are the links [blue and underlined](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105530/gmail-app-links-are-not-clickable) or are they just plain text?

Comment: Plain text. There is no indication that the links are clickable.

Comment: I have this issue on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro with Android 10 and latest version of Gmail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the problem on two different HTC devices. It did work in html emails as well as text only mails. As far as I can tell it does not seem to be a general problem of the app but you can try to uninstall all updates of the app since you are not able to completely remove it. Therefore just go to Settings -> Apps -> gmail -> Uninstall Updates.

Comment: AHHHH! I may have discovered the issue when trying to uninstall all versions. I forgot I added corporate email which added a bunch of high security controls to the phone. Not positive thats the issue, but I'm willing to bet that's whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail app has had occasional non-clickable link issues in the past, especially with plain text messages. But these tend to get fixed quickly. However, your issue does not seem to be due to the GMail app. Sometimes Anti-Malware or Anti-Virus apps with hyper-active spam filters can disable links in your email. Try disabling or re-configuring such apps.

Alternatively, you could switch to the more modern GMail alternative from Google, viz. [Inbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox).

Comment: Everything is set default. No spam filters. No anti Virus. The app has updated several times. There are no settings that I can find that disable this feature, and I appreciate the "Inbox" suggestion, but that app looks terrible. Not crazy about Google deciding for me whats important. Cant see with that app where one email ends and the other begins.

Comment: The big difference with Inbox is a new feature called bundling. It can be quite irritating. You can easily turn off the bundling in Settings. Then it will behave like the Gmail app.